# Apartment's Hallway Lights Controlled By My Unit's Circuit Breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, meter

I manually flipped a breaker before doing work in my bathroom and noticed that the apartment hallway light is controlled by my unit's circuit breaker. Does this mean that I get billed for the hallway light usage? Are electric meters and breakers always linked?

Comment: That's a question for your superintendent. We can't possibly know with the information at hand.

Comment: Is it just the light in front of your door?  Yes, one electric panel is always running off of one meter.  One meter could conceivably have more than one panel.

Comment: If the breaker that controls your bathroom also controls the hall light, then it is likely you are paying for the hall light energy use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a lamp is on **one** circuit.  A circuit is powered by **one** circuit breaker (hopefully!!)  In North American practice (and most others), a circuit breaker sits in a service panel.   Any service panel is fed by **only one** electric meter, because of billing and safety/Code*.

Modern building and landlord codes require either a) a separate meter for the Commons Areas separate from any tenant meters, b) everything on one meter and the landlord pays the electricity, or c) the landlord uses *sub-metering* to divide the complex as in a).  However, these are fairly recent Code changes, and old buildings are *grandfathered* (do not need to be upgraded simply because Code changes).

However, this may not mean *you're paying* for the hall light.  Lights which are on at certain specific times **use a known amount of power**.  For instance, look at any town's street lights.  They do not have meters. Nor does the city have its own power distribution system; they are simply clipped onto the utility's 120/240V/277V/480V distribution.  How are they billed, then?  Easy: it's known how much energy the light fixture draws, and most parts of the world, night averages 12 hours a day.

So in similar vein, you could compute the lights' draw and ask the landlord for a rent concession for that amount; however *most likely, he'll tell you that's already been done and is already factored into the rent*.  So, there you are.

---

---

---

* If someone really, really, really wanted to power a panel from 2 meters, one could use a generator-style interlock to isolate them but allow the meter to power from one or the other.  It would be sheer madness to wire it to draw from 2 meters at once.